# Felix and OSGi - How to specify Parent and Abstract Classes

Tags: java, apache-karaf, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

I am using Apache Felix with BluePrint for the Dependency configuration.

I have a usecase where Abstract Parent and Child classes are involved. How the dependancy is mapped in the Blueprint for these classes. i am not able to see the Abstract & Parent fields in the BluePrint.xml (It fails saying parent and Abstract and Parent are not valid fields )

```
<bean id="parentAbstractClass"
    class="com.sun.AbstractClass">
    <property name="data1" ref="data1" />
    <property name="data2" ref="data2" />
</bean>

<bean id="ImplClass"
    class="com.sun.ImplClass" />
```

Java Class:

```
 Class AbstractClass {

}

Class ImplClass extends AbstractClass {

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Why not simply use the concrete class on top and set all fields on it?

Comment: Could you please provide a full version of blueprint.xml and stack trace of the failure you observe?